# Solve $y[x]$ by using the WKB approximation and how fitting {a Cos[bx] Exp[-cx]} with this plot of $y[x]$

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics

I have an equation:
$$y[x]=\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{|k(x)|}}e^{-\int^x k(x')dx'}\qquad\text{(1)}$$

Where

$$k(x)=\sqrt{\dfrac{w^2}{c^2}+\left(\dfrac{w(w_p)^2}{c^2v_t h}\right)(A1)}$$

$$A1=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int\dfrac{e^{-y^2}}{y-\dfrac{w+2iR-om}{v_t(\dfrac{w}{c}(1-\dfrac{(1-\dfrac{x}{L})}{1+\dfrac{w_c}{w}})^{\dfrac{1}{2}})}}dy$$

This expression $\int^x \sqrt{\dfrac{w^2}{c^2}+\left(\dfrac{w(w_p(x'))^2}{c^2v_t h(x')}\right)A1(x')}dx'$... (2) means that:

At first I must solve $\int^x \sqrt{\dfrac{w^2}{c^2}+\left(\dfrac{w(w_p(x'))^2}{c^2v_t h(x')}\right)A1(x')}dx'$ , then change $x$ to $x'$ .

But it has an error. Why? Because I get $A1(x')$ numerically and put its answer to (2), so it will be mistake. In fact I can't solve the indefinite integrate (2) because $A1$ is solved numerically, so the error is right.

The plot of the equation (1) muse be as below:
[image]

The condition is $y[-L]=10$ or $y[-L]=0$ and $L=0.00001$. the others show in the program.

```
R = ((1 - x/L)*W^2*(16*10^-20)^2*Pi*Sqrt[me]*LnLumbda)/( T^(3/2)*e0);

Simplify[
  1/Sqrt[π] E^-S^2/(S - (W + 2 I R - Om)/
    (vt (W/CC (1 - (1 - x/L)/(1 + (Wc)/W))^(1/2))))]
```

> ```
> -((0.5641895835477563 E^-S^2 Sqrt[x]) /
>   ((0.016006834477809786 + 0.00008178287140291831 I) - 1. S Sqrt[x] - (0. + 8.178287140291829 I) x))
> ```

```
A1[x_] := 
  NIntegrate[
    -((0.5641895835477563 E^-S^2 Sqrt[x])/
      ((0.016006834477809786 + 0.00008178287140291831 I) - 1. S Sqrt[x] -          (0. + 8.178287140291829 I) x)), 
    {S, -∞, ∞}]

yWKB[x_] := b/Sqrt[Abs[κ[x]]] Exp[NIntegrate[κ[xp], {xp}]]

κ[x_] := Sqrt[W^2/CC^2 + (W wp^2)/(CC^2 vt k) A1[x]]

Simplify[κ[x]]
```

> ```
> Sqrt[(3.947841760435743`*^13 Sqrt[
>   x] + (6.319244960388013`*^11 - 
>     6.319244960388012`*^16 x) NIntegrate[-((
>     0.5641895835477563` E^-S^2 Sqrt[
>      x])/((0.016006834477809786` + 0.00008178287140291831` I) - 
>      1.` S Sqrt[
>       x] - (0.` + 
>         8.178287140291829` I) x)), {S, -∞, ∞}])/Sqrt[x]]
> κ[x_] := √(3.947841760435743`*^13 + 
>     1/Sqrt[x] (6.319244960388013`*^11 - 
>        6.319244960388012`*^16 x) NIntegrate[-((0.5641895835477563` \
> E^-S^2 Sqrt[
>            x])/((0.016006834477809786` + 0.00008178287140291831` I) - 
>            1.` S Sqrt[
>             x] - (0.` + 
>               8.178287140291829` I) x)), {S, -∞, ∞}])
> ```

```
yWKB[-L]
```

> NIntegrate::ilim
>
> ```
> 0.0004027134076113933` b E^NIntegrate[κ[xp], {xp}]
> ```

```
Solve[0.0004027134076113933 b E^NIntegrate[κ[xp], {xp}] == 10, b]
```

> NIntegrate::ilim
>
> ```
> {{b -> 24831.554676346186` E^(-1.` NIntegrate[κ[xp], {xp}])}}
> ```

```
Plot[Abs[yWKB[x]], {x, -L, L}]
```

So how do I solve `y[x]`

**Update**

**My answer to the question is**

```
(* ClearAll *)
W = (2.*Pi*3.*10^14);
CC = 3.*10^8;
me = 911.*10^-33;
T = 16.*10^-16;
vt = ((2.*T/me)^(1/2));
Wc = 16.*10^-20;
L = 1.*10^-5;
wp = W*Sqrt[(1 - x/L)];
Om = Wc;
e0 = 885.*10^-14;
LnLumbda = 10.;
k = W/CC (1 - (1 - x/L)/(1 + (Wc)/W))^(1/2);
R = ((1 - x/L)*W^2*(16*10^-20)^2*Pi*Sqrt[me]*LnLumbda)/( T^(3/2)*e0);


Simplify[1/Sqrt[\[Pi]]
   E^-S^2/(S - (W + 2 I R - Om)/(
    vt (W/CC (1 - (1 - x/L)/(1 + (Wc)/W))^(1/2))))]
```

> -((0.56419 E^-S^2 Sqrt[x])/((0.0160068 + 0.0000817829 I) - 
>      1. S Sqrt[x] - (0. + 8.17829 I) x))

```
A1[x_] := 
 NIntegrate[-((0.5641895835477563` E^-S^2 Sqrt[
       x])/((0.016006834477809786` + 0.00008178287140291831` I) - 
       1.` S Sqrt[
        x] - (0.` + 8.178287140291829` I) x)), {S, -Infinity, 
   Infinity}]


Simplify[(W^2/ (CC^2) + ((W (wp)^2)/((CC^2) vt k )) A1[x])]
```

> 3.94784*10^13 +   1/Sqrt[x] (6.31924*10^11 - 6.31924*10^16 x) NIntegrate[-((
>        0.56419 E^-S^2 Sqrt[x])/((0.0160068 + 0.0000817829 I) - 
>         1. S Sqrt[
>          x] - (0. + 8.17829 I) x)), {S, -[Infinity], [Infinity]}]

```
Coef[x_] := 
 3.947841760435743`*^13 + 
  1/Sqrt[x] (6.319244960388013`*^11 - 
     6.319244960388012`*^16 x) NIntegrate[-((0.5641895835477563` \
E^-S^2 Sqrt[
         x])/((0.016006834477809786` + 0.00008178287140291831` I) - 
         1.` S Sqrt[
          x] - (0.` + 
            8.178287140291829` I) x)), {S, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]

DE = {(y''[x] + Coef*y[x]) == 0, y'[-L] == 0, y[-L] == 10};
sol = NDSolve[{(y''[x] + Coef[x]*y[x]) == 0, y[-L] == 10, 
   y'[-L] == 0}, y, {x, -L, L}]
```

> {{y -> InterpolatingFunction[{{-0.00001, 0.00001}}, <>]}}

```
Plot[Abs[y[x] /. sol], {x, -L, L}]
```

> [image]

**please help me for fitting {`a Cos[bx] Exp[-cx]`} with this plot**

Comment: It looks likes you are trying to tabulate and plot the formal solution of some ordinary differential equation (ODE). It might be simpler to directly solve the original ODE using the NDSolve function.

Comment: @yarchik Can you work answer about NDSolve function

Comment: Tell us what the differential equation is

Comment: @QuantumDot From what I understood, the OP uses the WKB approximation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKB_approximation) to describe some kind of tunnelling problem in quantum mechanics. What is disturbing with such kind of posts is that no complete code with all the definitions is given.

Comment: the code is not reproducible; one problem that pops up is that `NIntegrate` needs to be called with a range for the variable to integrate over (check the definition of `yWKB`); also there are duplicate definitions eg for `κ`; it's not clear what are the values of the various parameters used

Comment: Yes, this does seem like a WKB approximation problem. It's probably easier to just punch the full Schrödinger equation into NDSolve here. It would help if OP would give the problem that they're trying to solve here (e.g., what is the potential? What are the initial and boundary conditions?). It's a bit difficult to take this kludge of formulae apart.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Can you work answer about NDSolve function

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Can you work answer about NDSolve function

Comment: Please update the post with the full Schrödinger equation you're trying to solve. With that we can probably help you.

Comment: the `NIntegrate::ilim` message occurs because the definition of `yWKB` does not include a proper range for `NIntegrate`; I am assuming it should be `yWKB[x_, b_] := 
 b Exp[-NIntegrate[κ[xp], {xp, -Infinity, x}]]/Sqrt[Abs[κ[x]]]`

Comment: @user42582 Can you work answer

Comment: @Emadkareem I am having trouble reproducing the input; even when I correct for syntactical errors, I get `NIntegrate::slwcon` messages; perhaps you should follow the suggestions in the comments and pursue a different approach

Comment: @user42582 see new update

Comment: @Emadkareem. Yours updated code dosen't work !

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk It works fine I will rewrite it

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk see new update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you give model `a*Cos[b*x]*Exp[-c*x]]` but I changed it to see below.
Because I tried and I failed with yours model. My model is:

> $$\left|a e^{-c x} \cos \left(b x^f+e\right)\right|+d$$

Extract data from `sol`:

```
data = Table[{x, (Abs[y[x] /. sol[[1]]])}, {x, 0, 10^-5, 1/100000000}];

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, Abs[a*Cos[b*x^f + e]*Exp[-c*x]] + 
d, {{a, 1.65*10^19}, {b, 10*10^7}, {c, 95000}, {d, 1.1*10^18}, {e,5.4}, {f, 1.3}}, x] // Normal

 (* 7.367209126*10^17 + 1.428920015*10^19 E^(-80771.84037 Re[x])
 Abs[Cos[5.515029542 + 1.439426425*10^9 x^1.507570798]]*)
```

and model is:

> $7.36721 10^{17}+1.42892 10^{19} e^{-80771.8 x} \left|\cos \left(5.51503\, +1.43943 10^9 x^{1.50757}\right)\right|$

```
Show[{ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[nlm, {x, 0, 10^-5}]}, 
PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]